# Wordpress on AWS ELB errors 302

Tags: wordpress, aws-elb

I am in the process of moving my EC2 web hosting environment to ELB. Static webpages work perfectly, but Wordpress sites (multisite) loops with 302.

Apache log reports that "GET /" but the hosting folder for Wordpress is "GET /wp/".

See curl:

```
 curl -v -k -H "Host: example.com" myELB.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/
* Connection state changed (MAX_CONCURRENT_STREAMS == 128)!
< HTTP/2 301 
< date: Wed, 03 Jun 2020 09:13:12 GMT
< content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
< content-length: 0
< location: https://example.com/
< server: Apache/2.4.29 (Ubuntu)
< x-redirect-by: WordPress
< 
* Connection #0 to host myELB.eu-west-1.elb.amazonaws.com/ left intact
* Closing connection 0
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out ELB communicates via port 80 to EC2. All I had to do was disable "Force SSL" on Wordpress and it worked (in my case it was a plugin).